# Desktop background not displaying ubuntu 19.4

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04, and now when ever wake my computer by opening the lid, the desktop background is replaced by white static.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround could be to restart Gnome:

Just press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then input `r`, then enter. 
The background will come back.